# Difference between const reference and reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference-value

```
void setage(const int&a);
void setage(int&a);
```

What is the difference between this two functions?
When this function is called?

Comment: Do you know what `const` does? In the second example, you would not be able to call it with `setage(5)`, since `5` cannot bind to a non-const reference.

Comment: Yes i know the const will make ensure that passed value will not be changed the value

Comment: so if you know what const is so what the question?

Comment: if this is overloaded in a class how object will differentiate the functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the overload set:

```
void setage(int&a) { std::cout << "&"; }
void setage(const int&a) { std::cout << "&c"; }
```

the first function is called *only* with variables that are non-const:

```
int a = 42;
setage(a);  // prints &
```

The second function is called if you pass it a variable that is const, or if you pass it a literal value:

```
int const b = 42;
setage(b);  // prints c&
setage(42);  // prints c&
```

Note that if this overload set is written within a class, the same rules apply, and which function is called still depends on whether the passed in argument is a literal, non-const variable, or const variable.

Comment: _"There is no difference in the behavior if this function is a member function of a class."_ ?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings It's a response to the last comment by the OP.

Comment: Oh I see, you mean the whole of the above applies also for member functions. Out of context it looks a bit like you are saying both functions are equivalent if they're member functions.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Fair enough, reworded.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Ok, the reworded edit was still confusing. Should be ok now.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` just means that the function will not change the value. When passing by reference, it's often preferred to pass by constant reference, unless the function is supposed to change the parameter.

As to which function gets called, it would depend on the variable type. See below example.

```
int a( const int &b ) { return b; }
int a( int &b ) { return ++b; }

int main() {
    int x = 2;
    a( x ); // calls a( int & b )
    a( 5 ); // calls a( const int &b )
    const int y = 7;
    a( y ); // calls a( const int &b )
}
```

Note that literal values (such as `5` in the above example) can not bind to non-`const` references.